# When I'm using CopyFromRecordset in VBA to translate data in an Excel spreadsheet, only a few of my recordset data are transfered

Tags: vba, excel, ado, recordset

I have trouble figuring what I'm doing wrong with CopyFromRecordset method in VBA. Here's a picture from the spreadsheet:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

As you can see, all columns are not filled. Here's a copy of my code:

```
    Private Sub btnRecherche_Click()
Dim rsRecherche As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As New Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(11)

Select Case cmbRechercheType.Value
Case "offre"
    If chk10der.Value = True Then 
        Set rsRecherche = getOffres(True)
    ElseIf txtIDStart <> "" And txtIDEnd <> "" Then 
        Set rsRecherche = getOffres(False, CInt(txtIDStart.Text), CInt(txtIDEnd.Text))
    Else 'Tout afficher
        Set rsRecherche = getOffres
    End If
Case "candidature"
    If chk10der.Value = True Then
```

[....]

```
       End If
End Select

If rsRecherche.Fields.Count > 0 Then
    'On rentre les données dans les cellules
    Range("Q13:AI660").ClearContents
    For col = 0 To rsRecherche.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.Cells(13, col + 17).Value = rsRecherche.Fields(col).Name
    Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(13, 17), ws.Cells(13, rsRecherche.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
    ws.Range("Q14:AI660").CopyFromRecordset rsRecherche 'That's where I use the CopyFromRecordset
End If
End Sub
```

And the function that call the Database (because yes, I'm not using Excel nor Access as my database but HeidiSQL) :

```
    Public Function getOffres(Optional ByVal der As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal startID As Integer = -1, Optional ByVal endID As Integer = -1) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlQuery As String
Set connect = New ADODB.Connection
connect.Open connString

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

If der Then
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM offre ORDER BY offre_ID desc LIMIT 10;"
ElseIf startID <> -1 And endID <> -1 Then
    If startID > endID Then
        MsgBox "La plage de numéro des enregistrements est incorrect !"
        Exit Function
    End If
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM offre WHERE offre_ID >= " & startID & " AND offre_ID <= " & endID & ";"
Else
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM offre INNER JOIN source ON offre.source_ID = source.source_ID;"
End If

rs.Open sqlQuery, connect

Set getOffres = rs
End Function
```

In this last picture the code goes into the Else part (as I want him to).

EDIT : I was searching for an answer when I stepped across this : [Record 256](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJxKo.png) it's the only record that return all of his data. I checked for a difference with other entries in my DB but I can't find one.

Comment: Couldn't upload the last picture cause I don't have 10 reputation points...

Comment: Are you only getting 10 records?

Comment: hi @ManishChristian I followed your advice, thank you for the comment !

Comment: @CLR No, I'm getting 200+ records but only 3 out of 12 columns are getting filled. Although : record N°256 get filled like I want to for some reason

Comment: try changing it to ws.Range("Q14").CopyFromRecordset rsRecherche. If you want copy to start from Row 14 and Col Q.

Comment: Try adding a new line before `rs.Open sqlQuery, connect` that reads `Debug.Print sqlQuery` to make sure that the right query is being called.

Comment: Hello @sumeet singh kushwah, I've tried to apply your changes but unfortunately it did not change. CLR, I checked in Debug mode, sqlQuery has the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution (without using CopyFromRecordset), here's a copy of the code :

```
If rsRecherche.Fields.Count > 0 Then
    'On rentre les données dans les cellules
    Range("Q13:AI660").ClearContents
    For col = 0 To rsRecherche.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.Cells(13, col + 17).Value = rsRecherche.Fields(col).Name
    Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(13, 17), ws.Cells(13, rsRecherche.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
    'ws.Range("Q14").CopyFromRecordset rsRecherche

    row = 14
    While Not (rsRecherche.EOF)
        For fillCol = 0 To rsRecherche.Fields.Count - 1
            ws.Cells(row, fillCol + 17).Value = rsRecherche.Fields.Item(fillCol)
        Next
        rsRecherche.MoveNext
        row = row + 1
    Wend
End If
```